# How to limit the scope of a "using namespace ..."? c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have file with "my namespace"'s (myns::) methods implementations, there are lots of "myns::" before functions. I want to write using namespace, but it will be visible in other files. I can't write "static" before "using namespace mysp;".

my_namespace_file.h:

```
namespace myns {
  void F1();
  void F2();
}
```

my_imp_file.h:

```
#include "my_namespace_file.h"

// problem is here
using namespace myns;

void F1() {}
void F2() {}
```

if I use here "using namespace myns;" and include my_imp_file.h in other files I will do not use in this files "myns::"

Comment: You can wrap implementations in namespace block too, then you won't need to repeat the namespace name? If that's not what you want, please show some code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: If it's an implementation file, you shouldn't have to include it anywhere

Comment: @THND Don't use `using namespace` statements in header files, at least at the global level, for exactly the reason you are discovering.  Use such statements only in implementation files, or inside of specific scopes, but certainly not at the global level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
#include "my_namespace_file.h"

namespace myns {

void A::F1() {} // class name must be repeated, because you cannot open namespace of the class
void A::F2() {}

}
```

---

Since you should never `#include` file with implementations, you can use `using namespace myns;` as well, but that may backfire if you will ever create another class `A` in a different namespace. Better to just use namespace correctly.

Comment: Just write "name space ... {}" again? Ok, I will try it

Comment: @THND Yes. Namespaces can be opened as many times as needed. There's no limit that you only do it once or anything like that.

Comment: It's ok to use it in this way? or it's better to write everywhere "myns::"

Comment: Pros/cons: creating a scope for a namespace instead of explicitly qualifying it around implementations is less noisy and easier to work with.  However, if it's a big namespace it's less clear what you're working with, or where names come from.  It is also easier to accidentally add new names to the namespace that you didn't mean.  If code makes use of many namespaces, lack of qualifications can get hard to keep track of, but if all the code is primarily using code form its own (single) namespace, then the open namespace scope is usually a better choice to reduce noise.

Answer (score 1):

niceheadername.h:

```cpp
namespace myns{
  extern void coolFunctionName(); // I exist!
}
```

nicecppfilename.cpp:

```cpp
#include "niceheadername.h" // I exist in "niceheadername.h"
void myns::coolFunctionName(){ // this is what I contain!
  //put content here
}
```

then, in all other files that you write `#include "niceheadername.h"` to tell the compiler where to find those functions.

Comment: oh btw, if you want to use the function in other files, you need to say `myns::coolFunctionName();`, or `using myns;`, because it's in a namespace

Comment: I know it, but I want to write something in file "nicecppfilename.cpp" so as not to write everywhere "myns::" (in this file), but if I use this in other files I must write "myns::"